# Can't play video in videoview android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I know that there is too many solutions were given, but I can't get the exact solution. My problem is that I have picked one video from internal storage device and after picking video then I have converted to String and set the video to videoView but then also it shows that "Can't play this video" in videoView.

can anyone please help me to find out the solution :(

here is my code

```
      File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Download/videos.mp4");
    Log.d("video",""+file);
    if (file.exists()) {
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        String video = String.valueOf(uri);
        Log.d("video",""+uri);
        videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(video));
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No video found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Nowadays it's better to use ExoPlayer, only use VideoView if you want to setup something quickly.

Comment: yes I know exoplayer is better but I can't understand after setting an uri to videoView why it dosen't play? @cmak

Comment: @AishaKumari if you're targeting new android APIs you'll have to use Scoped Storage or get the manage files permission

Comment: can you please show me an example, if you can @cmak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With scoped storage (required from API 30) you can't access files directly unless you request the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` (on Google Play you need to request it to Google).

The new way is to use the file uri. You can try those ways:

1. Ask the user to select the file.

```
private final ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> openDoc =
    registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument(),
      new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
          // use uri
        }
      });
```

Call it with:

```
// Use the mimetype you want (optional). Like "text/plain"
openDoc.launch(new String[]{"text/plain"});
```

Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#java)

2. Get the Media file uri with MediaStore

Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media)

You'll also need the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission if the file was not created by your app.